# Linux screen snapshot/redirect

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Is it possible to take a "snapshot" of a running screen command, either stored as text or an image? Something akin to the following:

```
screen -S myscreen -d -m ...
screen-screenshot myscreen > output.1 # does this exist?
screen-screenshot myscreen > output.2
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to take so called "hard copy" of a screen session:

```
screen -X -S 11534.test hardcopy hc.n
```

Here we send `hardcopy hc.n` command to screen session `11534.test`. The session name is available in the list of sessions(`screen -ls`).

The `hardcopy` command writes currently displayed image to the file(particularly, `hc.n`). The file is viewable via pagers(`less`, `more`, etc.) and text editors.